# Google Cloud SQL Server 2017 is marked for unload due to memory pressure

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-sql, memory-pressure

We are running **Google Cloud SQL server 2017 Express** with some databases.
It often happens that one database may crash and the instance is not accessible, we are forced to restart the instance in order to resume work. We have tried to change maximum server memory but the problem continues to occur. The **error** that is written on the logs is: mssql master sys runtime .1) is marked for unload due to memory pressure . I would be grateful for a solution proposed by you.

Comment: There's not any detail to go on here. Have you tried contacting Google Cloud support?

Comment: Do you have any error-logs/messages? What do you mean by crash? Unreachable/slow response/... ? Please provide more details.

Comment: Yes, the instance is unreachable. The error that is written on the logs is: mssql master sys runtime .1) is marked for unload due to memory pressure .

Comment: We also have contacted the Google Cloud Support team and they suggested to follow the SQL server documentation, where we found the suggested solution with maximum server memory that we have tried , but nothing solved.

Comment: I saw in “forum.red-gate” that the issue could be related to the default port for TCP/IP. check the link: https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/20413/sql-instance-is-unreachable-cannot-connect